# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 13 23:58:30 IST 2014"

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I am converting date format but instead getting error. I know that the question is repeated the solution was not helping:
Below is my code and the date field I am  converting is in format:
"2014-05-13T23:58:30.457"

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",Locale.US)
val format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM",Locale.US)

val result = data.filter{line=>{line.trim().startsWith("<row")}}
    .filter{line=>{line.contains("PostTypeId=\"1\"")}}
    .flatMap { line=>{
      val xml = XML.loadString(line)
      xml.attribute("CreationDate")
    }}.map{line=>{
      (format2.parse(format.parse(line.toString()).toString()),1)
    }}.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

And I am getting below error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 13 23:58:30 IST 2014"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at StackOverflowAnalysis.TotalQues$$anonfun$5.apply(TotalQues.scala:23)
    at StackOverflowAnalysis.TotalQues$$anonfun$5.apply(TotalQues.scala:22)
```

Comment: `format2.parse` should probably be `format2.format`

Comment: Its working. But I dont understand why parse not working

Comment: First of all, `java.util.Date` is legacy and you should not use it.  You should instead look at the appropriate classes in the `java.time` package.  Second of all, the reason it's not parsing is because the string does not match the format your parser is expecting.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Format: to convert from a date-time object (here `Date`) to a string, typically for presentation or data exchange. Parse: the opposite conversion from a string to a date-time object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String line = "2014-05-13T23:58:30.457";
    String reformatted = YearMonth.from(LocalDateTime.parse(line)).toString();
    System.out.println(reformatted);
```

This prints

> 2014-05

No use for specifying any formatters explicitly. Your field is in ISO 8601 format, the format that `LocalDateTime` and the other classes in java.time parse as their default. java.time is the modern Java date and time API. `YearMonth` is a month in the calendar, as the class name says, a year and a month. Just what you need. And its `toString` method formats it into your desired format of `yyyy-MM`, which conforms with ISO 8601 too.

### The outdated and the modern date and time classes

The classes you were using, `SimpleDateFormat` and implicitly `Date`, are long outdated and the former in particular notoriously troublesome. I recommend you avoid them. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code

- To **parse** means to analyse a string in order to determine the meaning of its contents. Here parsing a date-time string converts the string to a date-time object (`Date` or `LocalDateTime`).
- To **format** means the opposite: to convert some data, here a date-time object, into a string, typically for human readability or for data transmission.

So your code took your string of `2014-05-13T23:58:30.457`. The `toString` call may be superfluous and just return the same string again. Then it *parses* it into a `Date` object, this works nicely. Calling `toString` on the `Date` formats it into the string `Tue May 13 23:58:30 IST 2014`, which is what you didn’t want to do. Then you tried to *parse* this string into a new `Date` object using the format `yyyy-MM`. Since the string didn’t have this format, this failed with the exception you saw.

### Links

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `format2.parse` into `format2.format`.

When using `.parse`, the defined format of `SimpleDateFormat` should be exactly the same as that of the String.

p.s. Special case: When using Restful API service, if there are differences between the backend server and local environment, the problem would show up as well.

(Additional info translated from Chinese website: https://vimsky.com/article/2736.html)